# Experimental Parameters and Unitary in a specific Boson Sampling Experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I tried to reproduce the data of one of the [four historically first BosonSampling](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphoton.2013.112) experiments. While they present the information in a very accessible form, unfortunatly I fail to understand some necessary details.

In particular, i can break down my misunderstanding in very simple terms:

Their experiment consists of a 5-mode chip in this configuration (Fig 1b in main text), where $t_i$ is the beam splitter transmissivities, and $\alpha_i$ and $\alpha_j$ are phases:
[image]

They show all of their experimental parameters in Table 1 of the Supplementary Information:

[image]

They show the corresponding unitary matrices in the SI info, eq (1) [theoretical], eq(2) [experimentally reconstructed]:

[image]
[image]

In particular, the red highlighted value is $U_{5,5}$, describing the transition between input mode 5 and output mode 5. This transition depends only on one beam splitter (with transmissivities t10=0.95).

**My apparent misunderstanding:**
$$ |5_{out} \rangle=U_{5,5} |5_{in} \rangle$$

If one photon inputs mode 5, the probability that it exits at output mode 5 is:
$$P(5_{out})=|\langle 5_{out}|5_{out} \rangle|^2=|U_{5,5}|^2$$

$P(5_{out})=0.005666$ ($P(5_{out})=0.020498$) for the theoretical Unitary (reconstructed Unitary).

In the experiment however, the reflection probability at BS10 is $R=(1-t_{10}^2)$=0.0975.

That value **is at least 4 times as large** as the value constructed from the Unitary.

> How can I understand the values of the unitary matrices from the experimental configurations of the BS network?